# How to search between date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that someone update this table every day.

I would like to create a view and instead of update this view manually like the guy does, I would like to make it automatic.

For example, today is 15/jun/2012 and the table is updated, the view must be updated (when runned) when that person update the table, automatically.

My trouble is how do I get the first day of a month to the last day wich the table is updated.

Comment: So is the table updated every day, or not?

Comment: yes it is updated everyday, but manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you need to check your table to the last modified date  and get the first day in the month when that happened?

If that's true you need something like:

```
DECLARE @maxdate DATETIME
SELECT @maxdate = MAX(ModifiedDate) FROM [yourTable]
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (DAY(@maxdate) - 1)*(-1), @maxdate)
```

Comment: You can't declare a variable in a view.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Of course, he can replace the variable with the select statement, but I separated the code so it's more readable on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The last day that the table has been updated must be today, right? Will the table ever contain data later than today? If not then you can say "WHERE >= beginning of this month", right? You can get the beginning of the current month using various string conversion and concatenation tricks, but the method I prefer is sticking to date math:

```
SELECT [First day of this month] = 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');
```

So in your view, you can limit it to data since the beginning of the current month by using this where clause:

```
WHERE date_col >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')
```

If you need to exclude data later than right now, you can add:

```
AND date_col < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**EDIT**

Your question said the table is updated every day. If this is actually not true, and you need to go from the last month that the table was actually updated, you can change the above to:

```
WHERE date_col >= (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 
  DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', MAX(date_modified)), 
  '19000101') FROM dbo.your_table)
```

Comment: @Maturano can you try to be a little more specific, please?

Comment: I will create a new table and get the informations instead of create a view. I will just populate this table with all informations necessary, because this guy who updates the first table, will just need this new one for export from sql to excel and then he will filter the data.

Comment: How is the new table going to help? Maybe you haven't described the problem accurately in the first place. <shrug>

Comment: UPPER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, GETDATE()),1,3))  since on the table where i get the date, the month is like JUN APR, MAR, MAI ...  i will just filter the month automatcally, this way i think the problem of date day will be resolved